# Почему переименовали мой аккаунт?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника

У меня был другой ник. Почему сменили?

Comment: Возможно, оно противоречило правилам. Какой ник был?

Comment: @eccs0103 https://archive.fo/8zZHD

Comment: @eccs0103, я не нашел такого правила.

Comment: Было бы неплохо также увидеть ссылку на архив с таким правилом, запрещающим похожие ники.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy — Identity Theft

> Users that misleadingly appropriate the identity of another person are not permitted.

Comment: И где ты тут увидел вводящие в заблуждение сведения о личности другого лица?

Answer (score 11):

Не стоит выдавать себя за другого. Если один участник осознанно меняет имя на совпадающее с другим известным участником, это не может быть рассмотрено как допустимое поведение. Поэтому вернули прежнее имя.

Старайтесь выбирать имя так, чтобы избежать подобных ситуаций.

Comment: [relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174588/why-cant-i-change-my-name-to-jon-skeet)

Comment: А есть адекватный список правил, под действие которого подпадает этот случай, или тут каждый герундий сам себе злобный Буратино?

Comment: Изменение ника по умолчанию не означает выдачу себя за другого. Или вы готовы представить иные доказательства, оправдывающие ваш поступок?

Comment: @Грузчик хочешь сказать, что 9 лет на ресурсе ты был "Грузчик" и внезапно вспомнил, что ты "Алексей Шиманский"?)) И тот факт, что в последнее время ты задал 20 низкокачественных вопросов, которые все заминусовали (некоторые аж до -5...-7), что пришлось удалять часть и тот факт, что ты не можешь смотреть кто минусовал и задавал об этом вопрос  (наверное для мести..) https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12385/191482  никак не повлияли на смену тобой ника?)) Почему именно "Алексей Шиманский", а не, скажем, "Билл Мюррей"?

Comment: Я хочу быть самым известным.

Comment: И я хочу сказать, что минусование вопросов - это мой пиар ход.

Comment: @Грузчик Во-первых из участников самые популярные это "Harry" и "VladD", а во-вторых - ты только что признался, что выдавал себя за другого человека.

Comment: Нет, совпадение имён и совпадение личностей - это разное. Чем Вам так нравится минусовать мои вопросы и ник на букву А?